# JavaScript inside jstl iteration

Tags: javascript, jstl

I have the following codes:

```
     <%int number=0;%>

    <c:forEach var="row" items="${tAdmin.rows}" varStatus="totalRow" step="1">
       <td><%=++number%></td>
      <td>
      <div id="content" style="table-layout:fixed; width:405px; word-wrap:break-word;">
      <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
            function load(){
                    var content='${row.content}';
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=content;
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=Utf8.decode(document.getElementById("content").innerHTML);     
            }
            window.onload=load;
    </script>
    </div>
    </td>
    </c:forEach>
```

The problem is that it only shows the result of the last content instead of printing it out line by line according to number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the right way to do it, but a simple solution would be use `addEventListener` instead `onload`:

```
<%int number=0;%>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${tAdmin.rows}" varStatus="totalRow" step="1">
   <td><%=++number%></td>
  <td>
  <div id="content<%=number%>" style="table-layout:fixed; width:405px; word-wrap:break-word;">
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
                var element = document.getElementById("content<%=number%>");
                element.innerHTML=Utf8.decode('${row.content}');     
        }, true);
</script>
</div>
</td>
</c:forEach>
```

In fact your code is using only the last "onload" because, when loading the page, it will execute the javascript `load` callback only when finish full loading it. So, each time you loop is executed, it updates the `load` callback reference for the last one, so when `onload` is triggered, the last only will be executed.

But your code has other errors too. The `content` id, repeats at the code lot of times, that will make your div `getElementById` useless, because you have lot of ids that are equal. Ids must be unique to work property.

To finish, it's not a good pattern to mix your HTML with scripts inside, is better to have you logic file (javascript file) outside, then it can make changes in your code when finish to load, reading the html that was generated. You also can create `data` attribute in your `div` then read it by the javascript to manage all itens with a specific `data` attributes.

To keep it simple, I will add an example:

```
<%int number=0;%>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${tAdmin.rows}" varStatus="totalRow" step="1">
   <td><%=++number%></td>
  <td>
  <div id="content<%=number%>" style="table-layout:fixed; width:405px; word-wrap:break-word;" data-content="${row.content}">
</div>
</td>
</c:forEach>
```

Now the script file (I'm using jQuery for this example works on any browser):

```
$(function() {
    $("[data-content]").each(function(item) {
        $(item).html(Utf8.decode(item.attr('data-content')));
    });
});
```

Comment: You can, but is not the right way. The question is why his onload get only the last element, my question solve his problem. But I said, isn't the right way to do, but you can do.

Comment: So, i simply replace that jQuery function inside addEventListener?

Comment: You can, but the `$(function() { ... });` is the same that `window.onload = function () { ... }` or `window.addEventListener('load', function () { ... });`

Answer (score 2):

What you are creating, if you view the page source in the browser, would look something like this (note the ${row.content} will have already been replaced on the server):

```
<td>0<td>
<td>
  <div id="content" style="table-layout:fixed; width:405px; word-wrap:break-word;">
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
        function load(){
                var content='The first row content';
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=content;
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=
                    Utf8.decode(document.getElementById("content").innerHTML);     
        }
        window.onload=load;
</script>
</div>
</td>
<td>1<td>
<td>
  <div id="content" style="table-layout:fixed; width:405px; word-wrap:break-word;">
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
        function load(){
                var content='Some different content';
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=content;
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=
                    Utf8.decode(document.getElementById("content").innerHTML);     
        }
        window.onload=load;
</script>
</div>
</td>
<td>2<td>
<td>
  <div id="content" style="table-layout:fixed; width:405px; word-wrap:break-word;">
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
        function load(){
                var content='Yet some more content';
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=content;
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=
                    Utf8.decode(document.getElementById("content").innerHTML);     
        }
        window.onload=load;
</script>
</div>
</td>
```

You're going to have many copies of `function load()` and many times where `window.onload` is assigned `window.onload=load;`

When this arrives at the browser and is interpreted, only the *last* definition of `function load()` will be in effect; only the *last* time you assign `window.onload=load;` means anything (because you keep replacing the value of window.onload) -- each redefinition of `load()` will replace the previous one - so only your *last* `var content='${row.content}';` is ever executed.

In addition, you will have many `<div>` tags with the same id of "content" and that's not allowed.

The content of each of those `<td><div>...</div></td>` blocks can be set by the JSP/JSTL itself on the server -- there is no need to set the innerHTML  via javascript.
You can use the `totalRow` varStatus that you set up to provide the number for the first `<td>` -- you don't need to increment your own counter.

You can use Expression Language (EL) to access the content value of each row.

Inline style="blah blah blah" sucks. Use that only if absolutely necessary.
Instead, put all this style in CSS targeting .contentbits:
   style="table-layout:fixed; width:405px; word-wrap:break-word;"
becomes

```
.contentbits {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:405px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

The page fragment becomes much simpler:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${tAdmin.rows}" varStatus="totalRow" step="1">
  <td>${totalRow}</td>
  <td>
    <div class="contentbits">${row.content}</div>
  </td>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: How about 'onload' and 'Utf8' stuff? How can we use them within your above-mentioned codes?

Comment: @DoniAndriCahyono - this approach doesn't require and 'onload' handler because no javascript is needed when doing things this way. All of the looping and content substitution is done on the server before the page is sent to the browser.  I use this approach quite a lot and (as I commented on Adrián's answer) I use UTF-8 encoded unicode end-to-end; the page encoding is set via the `Content-Type` response header as `text/html;charset=utf-8` ... I don't have to put anything in the page.